# Python Twitter API - Set Display Picture and Description

Tags: python, api, twitter

I'm trying to set up the Twitter API to change a Twitter account display picture and description. After setting the API keys and telling it to do it's magic, I can get through without any errors, except after checking the Twitter account and finding none of my changes applied. I've tried various different methods by sending the most simple descriptions and pictures through the API but still got nothing. What is it I'm doing wrong? Any help is appreciated!

```
import twitter
twitterAPI = twitter.Api(consumer_key=twitterConsumerKey,
                        consumer_secret=twitterConsumerSecret,
                        access_token_key=twitterAccessToken,
                        access_token_secret=twitterAccessTokenSecret,
                            )

twitter.User().SetProfileImageUrl("http://website.com/image.jpg")
twitter.User().SetDescription("Hello there")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
twitterAPI.User().SetProfileImageUrl("http://website.com/image.jpg")
twitterAPI.User().SetDescription("Hello there")
```

You are calling the module instead of the object.

Comment: That I've tried as well, I get an error saying that Api has no attritube "User". Good guess though!

Answer (score 0):

Switched over to using Tweepy, as python-twitter doesn't actually have the ability to change the description or profile image.